# Extract value from cookie

Tags: python, django

With `_ga = request.COOKIES.get('_ga')` I e.g. `GA1.1.1432317817.1125843050`. I now have to define everything behind `GA1.1.`in a new variable. However, `GA1.1.` could also be `GA1.2.` etc. The dots are consistent.

How would you extract it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str.split`

**Ex:**

```
a = "GA1.1.1432317817.1125843050"
b = a.split(".", 2)[-1]
print(b)
```

**Output:**

```
1432317817.1125843050
```